# How can i set custom background colors of seaborn heatmap fields? (matplotlib collections.QuadMesh facecolors, Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I want to set the background color of some fields of a seaborn heatmap AFTER it has been created (customising some colours based on their position).

I am able to access the `facecolor` values via the matplotlib `collections.QuadMesh` object. When I modify the values (I have tried different ways) the changes get reflected, but the facecolors shown when displaying or exporting the plot stay unchanged.

What am I missing here?

This is a (non-)working example:

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.testing
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.collections import QuadMesh
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

CUSTOM_BACKGROUND = np.array([0.35, 0.8, 0.55, 1.0])

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 1], 'col2': [2,2]})
matrix_size = df.shape[0]
ax = sns.heatmap(df)
quadmesh = ax.findobj(QuadMesh)[0]
facecolors_old = quadmesh.get_facecolors()
facecolors_new = facecolors_old.copy()
facecolors_new[1] = CUSTOM_BACKGROUND

# Not working:
quadmesh.set_facecolors(facecolors_new)
# quadmesh._original_facecolor = facecolors_new
# facecolors_old[1] = CUSTOM_BACKGROUND
# quadmesh._facecolors[1] = CUSTOM_BACKGROUND

# works:
# quadmesh.set_facecolors('none')

# tests pass:
facecolors_actual = quadmesh.get_facecolors()
numpy.testing.assert_array_equal(facecolors_new, facecolors_actual)
facecolors_actual = quadmesh._facecolors
numpy.testing.assert_array_equal(facecolors_new, facecolors_actual)
# NOTE: inspecting `quadmesh._facecolors` however shows the old values!

# shows old colors
plt.show()
```

Dependency versions:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
pandas = "^1.2"
seaborn = "^0.11.2"
```

Remark:

This approach used to work for me before updating the dependencies. I have adapted some code from here for drawing custom confusion matrixes using the same approach: [pretty-print-confusion-matrix](https://github.com/wcipriano/pretty-print-confusion-matrix/blob/8f5688b138b6ab0fa2678cb74fb4e8d602027b08/confusion_matrix_pretty_print.py#L87)

Comment: `pcolormesh` (internally used by `heatmap`) updates the colors in the resulting `QuadMesh` based on the data when drawing (if you add `ax.figure.draw_without_rendering()` before the asserts you'll see that they fail). I guess there's not way to achieve what you want, you could only mask some fields which will then not be drawn, i.e. they will show the axes background color (which you can set as you like, but all masked fields will have the same background color then, so I think this is not what you want)

Comment: When I try your code in an interactive PyCharm session, it works without problem (matplotlib 3.4.3).

Comment: @JohanC do you really get a green square in the top right corner?

Comment: @JohanC Interesting. I cannot reproduce with that matplotlib version. Which seaborn version are you using? I have to add that the approach actually did work for me, probably until i bumped some dependencies. I have added a remark in the question respectively.

Comment: @Stef thanks for the comment. I don't get why there is a `set_facecolors` function when one is not actually able to set the colours after creation. when `pcolormesh` updates the colors as you say, why can't I do the same manually? Can you please elaborate why `ax.figure.draw_without_rendering()` causes the assertions to fail? I have a hunch that this might lead to the cause of the problem.

Comment: `draw_without_rendering()` draws the figure and causes `pcolormesh` to assign colors to the quadrilateral according to the color-mapped values. It creates a `QuadMesh` in the process, whose colors you can change, but this will have no effect on the figure as each time the figure is drawn, colors are being assigned according to the color-mapped values (first argument of `pcolormesh`).

Comment: @Stef i cannot find a documentation for `draw_without_rendering()`. Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.draw_without_rendering

Comment: `draw_without_rendering()` was added only recently, for older versions of mpl you can use `ax.figure.draw(ax.figure.canvas.get_renderer())` (i.e. drawing with rendering)

Comment: I worked around the problem for now by creating my own scalar color array and calling `axes.pcolormesh(...)` with it. Using the same `axes` object this will simply overwrite the old color values.

Still it would be nice to have the full flexibility of changing RGBA colors not just scalar colormap values.
Please let me know if you have any idea.
This is the related matplotlib discussion: https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/set-custom-background-colors-with-collections-quadmesh-set-facecolors/22536

Comment: Any updates on this? The `pcolormesh` workaround is not really suitable when using multiple different colormaps.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I just implemented a workaround https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/set-custom-background-colors-with-collections-quadmesh-set-facecolors/22536/3

Comment: Note, this really used to work but after an update to Python 3.9 (from 3.6) in my case it also stopped. :/ Besides masking with an overlay heatmap on top there is also another very simple alternative that can be applicable to some readers here. Since I am rendering the heatmap as an SVG to be used in an HTML, my workaround has been to directly manipulate the patches inside the SVG file with BeautifulSoup. All quad-patches in a heatmap are in order and can be identified by the attribute "clip-path" in the SVG file. Just replace the color of the fill style attribute with your own custom color.